# copy, paste selection based on multiple criteria to another worksheet in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, copy, paste

I'm very new to VBA and have been using the Macro recorder to create Macros. The Macro recorder can only take me so far, I'm able to accomplish 2/3 of what I need done.

I'm trying to create a Macro where I need criteria met in three Columns, copy the row that meets the criteria, and paste it onto a workbook. The criteria are "Open" "Critical" and "Date." 
Here's the tricky part, the date either needs to be greater than a specific date, either through user input or referencing a cell in a third worksheet. There are a few thousand rows, and about 19 columns, and all the codes I've attempted lead to crashing excel.

Sample of the code to getting the first two criteria:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_owssvr").Range.AutoFilter Field:=12, _
    Criteria1:="Open"
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_owssvr").Range.AutoFilter Field:=16, _
    Criteria1:="Critical"
Range("Table_owssvr").Select
Range("Q83").Activate
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

A-----------------------------------------------------------------B-----------------------------------------------------------C
Open                       -------------------------------------------------------Critical--------------------------------------------------1/25---Open-------------------------------------------------------High------------------------------------------------------3/25
Closed----------------------------------------------------Critical----------------------------------------------------3/24
Open------------------------------------------------------Critical-----------------------------------------------------1/25

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to be writing VBA you will have to eventually stop relying on .Select. Recorded code is fine short term but it is typically verbose and inefficient.

```
Option Explicit

Sub wqewqwew()
    Dim col1 As Long, col2 As Long, col3 As Long, dt As Date
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws2 = Worksheets("sheet2")

    With Worksheets("sheet1").ListObjects("Table_owssvr")
        With .HeaderRowRange
            col1 = Application.Match("open", .Cells, 0)
            col2 = Application.Match("critical", .Cells, 0)
            col3 = Application.Match("date", .Cells, 0)
            dt = CDate(Application.InputBox(prompt:="greater then when?", Title:="pick date", Default:=Date))
        End With
        With .Range
            .AutoFilter
            .AutoFilter field:=col1, Criteria1:="open"
            .AutoFilter field:=col2, Criteria1:="critical"
            .AutoFilter field:=col3, Criteria1:=">" & dt
        End With
        With .DataBodyRange
            If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                .Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            End If
        End With
        With .Range
            'turn off filters
            .AutoFilter
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

You will likely want to research error control and add some to the above.

Recommended reading: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/28700020#28700020).

Comment: WOW this worked FLAWLESSLY! Just had to change the col1,col2,col3 names to their appropriate column name! And yes definitely, I notice a huge performance issue when I use the .select, iterating over thousands of rows of data, I can definitely integrate my code with your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I designed it this way.
Try it.

The complete file is below the link

[Download File](http://cowtransfer.com/s/7i6i6yuf7iqu)

Sheet1 : It's your row data and click function button

Sheet2 : It's mapping data according to "Open" & "Critical" & "Date"
(The "Date" entered according to Sheet3)

Sheet3 : Enter the date you want

The complete code is as follows

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Click_Click()

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 2 To Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i) = "Open" And _
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i) = "Critical" And _
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i) > Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A2") Then

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```